# How to show horizontal divider in Vim editor

Tags: vim, customization, command-line-interface

[image: My vim environment with split panes.]

I recently downloaded a new theme  for my iterm2 and noticed that when I use multiple panes with Vim, the horizontal divider disappeared. What do I need to update in my vimrc to make it appear again?

I am using the theme [Monokai](http://chriskempson.github.io/base16/#monokai) and I'm in 256 colorspace. I'm using the following custom colors in my vimrc:

```
 highlight clear SignColumn
 highlight VertSplit    ctermbg=236
 highlight ColorColumn  ctermbg=237
 highlight LineNr       ctermbg=236 ctermfg=240
 highlight CursorLineNr ctermbg=236 ctermfg=240
 highlight CursorLine   ctermbg=236
 highlight StatusLineNC ctermbg=238 ctermfg=0
 highlight StatusLine   ctermbg=240 ctermfg=12
 highlight IncSearch    ctermbg=3   ctermfg=1
 highlight Search       ctermbg=1   ctermfg=3
 highlight Visual       ctermbg=3   ctermfg=0
 highlight Pmenu        ctermbg=240 ctermfg=12
 highlight PmenuSel     ctermbg=3   ctermfg=1
 highlight SpellBad     ctermbg=0   ctermfg=1
```

Comment: Your status bar (airline?) looks messed up. I've seen this before, and I think it was when I was inadvertently setting colorscheme twice. Might you have two colorscheme statements?